# How to dodge histogram bars in base R?

Tags: r, graphics

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html

ggplot2 can dodge bars. Is there a way to dodge histogram bars instead of overlaying them one on top of another in basic R (base graphics)"?

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-plot-multiple-histograms-in-r/

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Dodging barplots makes sense, but dodging histograms always seems like a bad idea - makes it much harder to see the shape of each distribution.

Comment: I doubt there's a built-in way, but you could probably hack one together, modifying the objects returned by `hist` and using `rect` directly. You can look at `graphics:::plot.histogram` to see how it's implemented

Comment: Yes. I have several histograms that are very similar. The default makes it hard to see the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you're asking but it's is a very poor visualization.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
#
set.seed(1)
dt  <- data.table(X1 = rnorm(1000), X2=rnorm(1000, 1))
ggplot(melt(dt), aes(x=value))+
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=variable), color='grey80', position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

You'd be better off using facets, or plotting the CDF, especially if the distributions are similar.

```
ggplot(melt(dt), aes(x=value))+
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=variable), color='grey80') + 
  facet_grid(variable~.)
```

[image]

```
##
# or plot cdfs together
#
ggplot(melt(dt), aes(x=value))+stat_ecdf(aes(color=variable), geom='line')
```

[image]

Comment: But I am asking basic R instead of ggplot2.

Comment: @user1424739 you might want to edit your question for clarity, the proper term is "base R" or in this case "base graphics". People may not understand "basic" to mean the same thing.